# OpenCV - Webcam imshow not displaying live feed, gray screen instead

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, computer-vision

I am working with OpenCV version 3.2.0 in Visual Studio 2015 and have been able to access my webcam until all of a sudden when I was working on it this morning. I can't figure out where this problem is coming from. I now get:

[image]

It doesn't throw any errors but it also doesn't show any input through the webcam

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;    

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n");
        return -3;
    }


    Mat image;
    namedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while (1)
    {
        cap.read(image);

        imshow("Image", image);
        waitKey(30);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Has anyone encountered this error before?

**Edit:**
Things I have looked at:

My webcams that I have work in things like Google Hangouts so I don't think it's a webcam issue.

Also, I uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 and installed Visual Studio 2017 to see if reinstalling would work and still get the same results.

**Edit:**

I am getting the error `<information not available, no symboles loaded for opencv_world320d.dll>` when I create a new `VideoCapture` object. I am pretty sure I have everything included correctly.

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories:
`$(OPENCV_BUILD)\include`

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General:
`$(OPENCV_BUILD)\x64\vc14\lib`

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input:
`opencv_world320d.lib`

Comment: try with: `Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;` inside the while loop and remove `Mat image` before the while.

Comment: @eyllanesc Negative. I used `image` instead of `frame` as you suggested

Comment: The creation of the Mat object must be within the loop.

Comment: Try this [example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#VideoCapture)

Comment: I removed all the extra stuff and it gave me the same screen. Without removing things it gives me a black screen because it is getting in a white one.

Comment: It started when I added VC to my project and don't know what could have caused it to change..

Comment: is image empty() after cap.read() or what about read() return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@michael scolfield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43812330/5184092), it was a problem with my antivirus blocking my webcam. I couldn't figure out how to exclude my Visual Studio directory so I just tried uninstalling it and it worked. It would be nice to have antivirus and have this working so I'll need to figure that out. But for temps this will work.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem after obtaining Opencv via compiling and building source using CMake.  Then, I deleted them and installed Opencv from prebuilt binaries. I have run the code again and there was no problem.

Comment: I downloaded the windows version from here http://opencv.org/releases.html, but I still get the same things

Comment: There is one more point also. My antivirus prevented the webcam access of a software. I disabled this property and solved.

Comment: I even checked my antivirus like six different times and excluded my Visual Studio directory everywhere I could. **But, uninstalling my antivirus did the trick...** Why this all of a sudden happened after months of working I have no idea. This has taken me way too long to figure out. It's kinda neat to know that my antivirus stops unwanted webcam peepshows though. Thanks for your help.